# Best way to take a line from the fuse box (in engine bay) to cabin?

Tags: opel, vauxhall, astra, fuse-panel

This may be a dumb question - I'm looking for the best way to take a line from an engine bay mounted fuse box to the cabin, without the threat of leakage/detritus entering the cabin - I'm looking into a DIY dash-cam hardwire install and just ultimately looking for do's/don't(s).

Vehicle is a Vauxhall (opel) Astra K (2017) - may also use same technique in future for internal mood lighting if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Any time you run wire from the engine bay to the cabin, the simple route is through an existing grommet in the firewall- they are designed for this, and many car brands have spares, or ones which can easily accommodate another wire.

For a 2017 Astra, the best places to look according to one of the Vauxhall Astra groups I read are:

- Pull the carpet back a bit under the glove box. There will be a large cable going to the bulk head with a grommet around it
- Or you could use the grommets in the fire wall for the heater matrix pipes